# jquery ui autocomplete loading graphic not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery autocomplete drop down list that is being populated by an ajax call. When the user starts typing, the expected behavior I am looking for is the default loading graphic to display which is found in the `ui-autocomplete-loading` css class. It seems that it's really there because when I block the UI thread using an alert box, I can see the spinner show up.

[image: UI Thread being blocked by alert box]

Once I remove the alert box and just let it run normally, the drop down UI locks while it's populating, never showing the spinner.

[image]

[image]

Here is my implementation of the auto complete function:

```
function SetupAllMFGsAutocomplete(source, inputObjectTextField) {
    var datafromServer = source;
    $(inputObjectTextField).val(savedUserInputValue);
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    $(inputObjectTextField).trigger('focus').attr('value', savedUserInputValue).trigger(e);
    $(inputObjectTextField).each(function () {
        // Setup autocomplete
        $(this).autocomplete({
            // Override the source function so we can perform the search by value instead of label
            source: function (request, response) {
                var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");

                var results = $.grep(datafromServer, function (value) {
                    return matcher.test(value.value);
                });

                if (results.length == 0) {
                    results = ['No Matches Found'];
                }

                response(results);

            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item.label === 'No Matches Found') {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(inputObjectTextField).val(ui.item.label);

                    // Set the input's value to the label instead
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                    // Add a modelid attribute to store the selected model's id for saving
                    $(this).attr("modelid", ui.item.id);

                    if ($(this).attr("id") != "ModelXlateTextBox")
                        Save($(this).attr("id"), $(this));

                }
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item.label === 'No Matches Found') {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Should I be implementing the `autocomplete` function differently?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just showing and disappearing quickly?

Comment: How much data holds the `datafromServer` variable? The `grep` could be really slow and blocking the browser.

Comment: The data being held has around 28,000 records in it.  Is there something better to use than the grep?